# Using odoo offline and transfer the data when the used device gets connected again to internet

Tags: python, odoo, offline

I already using Odoo in my corporation and works well but there is some issues I have to deal with, for example I have to insert data using the odoo web app but in some cases I have fill odoo forms with a tablet outside of internet coverage area. My question is, there is a way to use Odoo offline?. There is a way to automatize the data transfer automatically when the tablet gets connected again to internet?. Thanks in advance, I appreciate any response.

Answer (score 3):

Its not possible with Odoo app. But if you make a custom app for special tasks, then it would be. For example `Odoo awesome timesheets` can be used offline.

If you can write custom app then you can sync your data using RPC interface. https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html